# What code do I use to embed launch rock into my external site?

Tags: iframe, embed, launch

I have a launch page that we built but we can't figure out how to embed launch rock widget into our site. Where do I find the embed code at? or How do I embed the widget into our page? Also how do I embed the sharing page into my site? When someone submits the signup form in the widget does it just take you to the launch rock sharing page?